# Display a SQL string coded with PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Is it possible to show a SQL string coded in PDO with prepared params like this ? :

```
$nom_client = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  client.IdClient,Nom_societe FROM client 
                                            LEFT JOIN intermediaire_has_client ON IdClient=intermediaire_has_client.Client_IdClient
                                            WHERE intermediaire_has_client.Intermediaire_IdIntermediaire=:id_inter");

$nom_client->bindValue(":id_inter",$_SESSION['num_agence'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$nom_client->execute();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking to see the final "query" with all parameters in it, then you are not going to be able to get what you are after from within your PHP code.

The way prepared statements work is that the based query with parameter placeholders is sent to MySQL and "prepared".  Follow on calls to MySQL just pass the parameters themselves.  As such the full query with parameters in it never exists.

Your best best is to log in your MySQL query log (you might have to configure MySQL to log all queries), where you will be able to see the final interpreted representation of the query.

Comment: A good way to see the query is this :  echo str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $requete->queryString);

Answer (score 1):

The SQL string is not being "coded". Placeholders are not copy-and-paste inserts. The query and the values really are sent as two separate parts to the database. The database sees the same "placeholder query" and gets the values separately.

Comment: Might also want to mention emulated prepare mode, which is equally as opaque.

Comment: Let's forgo emulated placeholders, since they shouldn't be used and they don't help either. :o)

Comment: true. But in the spirit of the OP's question, is it possible to view the values after PDO does its escaping magic?

Comment: Not that I know of, even with emulated queries.